# Error reading tibbles into the mi package with missing_data.frame command

Tags: r, dataframe, missing-data, tibble

I have encountered unexpected behaviour (at least, unexpected by me) when working with the brilliant *mi* package, for missing data imputation, and tibbles.

Let's assume a tibble called B. The offending command is :-

```
A <- missing_data.frame(B)
```

The resulting error message is :-

> Error in .guess_type(y, favor_ordered, favor_positive, threshold, variable_name) [[Name of first variable in B]] must be a vector

This example reproduces the behaviour.

```
# Make the test data frames  and tibbles
Numbers <- sample(seq(1:200),40)
Numbers2 <- sample(seq(1:200),40)
Numbers3 <- sample(seq(1:200),40)
Letters <- sample(letters,40,replace=TRUE)

#Mixed numeric and character data
DF.test <- data.frame(Numbers,Letters)
    str(DF.test) #Number, Factor

DF.test2 <- data.frame(Numbers,Letters,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    str(DF.test2) #Number, Character

Tibble.test <- data_frame(Numbers,Letters)
    str(Tibble.test)  #Number, Character

# Run the tests
DF.mdf <- missing_data.frame(DF.test) # Fine
DF2.mdf <- missing_data.frame(DF.test2) # Fine

Tibble.mdf <- missing_data.frame(Tibble.test) # ERROR
Tibble.mdf <- missing_data.frame(data.frame(Tibble.test)) # Fine

#Purely numeric data
Tibble.test2 <- data_frame(Numbers,Numbers2,Numbers3)
str(Tibble.test2) # Number, Number, Number

# Run the tests
Tibble.mdf2 <- missing_data.frame(Tibble.test2) # ERROR
Tibble.mdf2 <- missing_data.frame(data.frame(Tibble.test2)) # Fine
```

It seems that *mi* objects to something in tibbles, but not in dataframes. The error message is unhelpful. It's easy to fix, by coercing the tibble back to a data frame, but I don't see a mention of this issue in the documentation. I am wholly unfamiliar with the innards of **mi**.

Am I missing something basic, or something in the documentation, or is this genuinely unexpected behaviour? All assistance, comments and interpretations are welcomed.

Comment: tibbles are not always compatible with data.frames. hadley decided on a hard break from the data.frame syntax for various reasons in part due to certain consistency of outputs. There are a number of questions on SO that are due to this incompatibility. Some packages rely on having a data.frame as input. This is likely one of those cases. In particular, `dat[, 1]` returns a vector if dat is a data.frame but returns a tibble if dat is a tibble. This seems to be the cause of this error as ` .guess_type` seems to want a vector.

Comment: https://github.com/cran/mi/blob/master/R/missing_data.frame.R  

    Looks like it explicitly casts matrices and lists using `as.data.frame()`, but it doesn't have any method for tibbles.

Comment: Thanks you both very much - an excellent explanation, and it draws my attention to some key difference between tibbles and datfarmes.

Comment: Rather than mark the question as solved in the question title, post the solution as an answer! Answering your own question is not forbidden (there is even an option to answer the question directly at the [Ask a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) page)

Comment: Good suggestion - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is this :-

Tibbles and dataframes behave almost identically, but not quite. One part of the behavious of a datframe that has changed is that the column subset operator.

D[, 1] returns a **vector** if D is a data.frame but returns a **tibble** if D is a tibble. the mi package wants a vector, and so complains.

Thanks to Imo and David Klotz for this answer.